# How to call fragments from activity in mvp pattern?

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

The problem is, I cannot move to the BookingFragment from DashboardActivity.

```
//BookingFragment
       companion object {
            fun start(): BookingFragment {
                val fragment = BookingFragment()
                return fragment
    
    
            }
```

```
//Calling back this function in activity inorder to move on that fragment
     fun getBookingView() {
            BookingFragment.start()
        }
```

```
//Fragment activity
     private lateinit var binding: FragmentBookingBinding
     override fun onCreateView(
                inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
            ): View? {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                val mvpKotlinApplication = AppApplication()
                DaggerBookingComponent.builder()
                    .appComponent(mvpKotlinApplication.get(requireActivity()).appComponent)
                    .bookingModule(BookingModule(activity as AppCompatActivity))
                    .build()
                    .inject(this)
```

//binding 
      binding = FragmentBookingBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
                val view = binding.root
                bookingView.start(binding)
                bookingPresenter.onCreateView()
                return view
        
            }

```
 //DashboardPresenter::
         private fun onClick() {
                dashboardView.getBookingObserable().doOnNext { dashboardModel.getBookingView() }
                    .subscribe()
            }
```

Comment: So, you can have a `DashboardNavigator`, and the `DashboardPresenter` can call `DashboardNavigator::goToBookingFragment()` or `DashboardNavigator::goToSomeOtherFragment()` and make the `DashboardActivity` attach different fragments to it.

Comment: in your particular case, `DashboardNavigator::goToBookingFragment()` will look like `BookingFragment.start()` and the rest of your `goTo...` methods will invoke a similar method on other fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to create a fragment container view in activity and proceed with fragment transaction. Please refer to docs - https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create

Basically you will have something like this:

```
<!-- res/layout/example_activity.xml -->
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />

fun getBookingView() {
    supportFragmentManager.commit {
        add(BookingFragment.start())
    }
}
```

Comment: @DmityMersiyanov I tried like this::: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/bookingFragment"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="?android:windowBackground"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
 
 
But as u suggested supportFragmentManager , doesnot support

Comment: try to replace supportFragmentManager to fragmentManager. And make sure that you call in your activity class.

But the first part of the code above should by in your activity_main.xml